# javascript changing href immediately on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have build javascripts that generate menus and sub menus from data base using AJAX, after I select option in menu I want it to pass it to next script that retrieves submenus for that option. Javascript code is:

```
$('#regionListPage').bind('pageinit', function(event) {
    var output = $('#output');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8888/test2/getregions.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status) {
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                var out = '<li><a href="subregions.html?reg=' + item.r_regionkey + '">' + item.r_name + '</a></li>';
                output.append(out).listview('refresh');
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see, it attaches URL value to each generated link with id number. When I select on link, it takes to another window where other js file is but that file only catches main menu href instead of attached one with a parameter, so that is why I can not retrieve sub menu elements from database. The question is, how can I change href to one with parameter immediately on click ? Thanks

Comment: Why not just change the `.attr('href', 'whatever.php')` or something?

Comment: @PHPglue I tried to change it to  `output.append(out).attr('href', "'subregions.html?reg=" + item.r_regionkey + "'").listview('refresh');` but the result was the same

Comment: @marty, no, you don't want to add `.attr()` to your `output` container, you want to add it to the `<a>` you are creating inside of your loop. See my answer for another way.